# Is there css to select text on a specific page?

Tags: css

I want to select text on a specific page and justify it.

At the moment I can justify it all by using

```
p {text-align: justify;}
div ( text-align: justify;}
```

But only want specific text, on specific pages, to be justified.

Basically, the only element which I want to text-align left is wpcf7. Everything else stays left apart from what I want to justify when I use

```
p {text-align: justify;}
```

I have the div class. entry-content, which didn't work, then I have a span class?? wpcf7-form-control-wrap.... –

So this might just be a question of whether i can left align text with wpcf7 using either

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap?
```

a span class, or

```
.entry-content
```

?

I'm guessing using

```
:content()
```

is out of the question?

Comment: Give it a class

Comment: No other way huh?

Comment: Basically, the only element which I want to text-align left is wpcf7.  Everything else stays left apart from what I want to justify. I have the div class. entry-content, which didn't work, then i have a span class?? wpcf7-form-control-wrap....

Comment: This question is also not clear. I miss the HTML code here to help you! Please update your question. We sadly don't have a glass sphere to see the code you mean. Do you want to center your contact form on the page or what?

Answer (score 0):

Put your text in a `<div>` with a `class` attribute, and then use the [CSS class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

```css
.justified{
    text-align: justify
}
```

```html
<p>
This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified. This text is not justified.
</p>
<p class="justified">
This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified. This text is justified.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's the only way. So long winded though, going into cpanel, finding file... Even Cpanel panics when I want to edit my php :-) nooooo, don't do ittt, goo back. Have you backed up... Lol.

Comment: I posted the answer :-) had div.entry-content amd just added label. Thanks for your kind help though.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {text-align: justify;} 

.entry-content label {text-align: left;}
```